# Drag & Drop Item on Top or In between items in ItemsControl WPF

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, itemcollection

In my MVVM WPF application, Drag & Drop is implemented in between two ItemsControls.
The DragOver & Drop methods are implemented in ItemCollectionViewModel.
The Item in the ItemCollection is EquipmentViewModel model class.

In Drop Method, I am checking targetItem like below
Case 1:
When I am dropping on top of the the other equipment the target TargetItem is Equipment and replacement logic works fine.

```
if (dropInfo.TargetItem is EquipmentViewModel targetEquipment)
 {
  // Equipment Replacement logic
 }
```

Case 2:
When I am dropping in between the items, the dropInfo.TargetItem is ItemCollectionViewModel. Now, I can't get the insert index of the target item collection.
it always add at the end.

```
if (dropInfo.TargetItem is ItemCollectionViewModel targetItemCollection)
 {
  // insert item in the targetItemCollection
 }
```

[image]

How to get the insert index in case 2 so that item can be inserted where dropped.